# nginx rewrite /api to root domain for SPA(Single page application)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, single-page-application

I am struggling to put a re-write nginx rule for SPA application. My application works at `https://example.com` and it also works on `https://example.com/api`. I want to rewrite. nginx rule ( or any other suggestion) in such a way when I type `https://example.com`, it should be served from `https://example.com/api` but the frontend domain should NOT redirect to it. I want to preserve https://example.com as it is.

I have done this for non-SPA application using nginx. But I am not sure how to do this for SPA(single page application) because `/api` is a URI not URL path.

As of now, this is the configuration:

```
location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                 rewrite / /api$ last;
        }
```

Comment: You could try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.html;`

Comment: sorry. Its not working . Although I have tried this already and I know on simple backend based routing it will work. But for SPA application /api comes from main index.html rendering. That's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use "kong API gateway" and implemented that.  nginx didnt work for me and I had to use ingress controlled which solved my problem.